# Laravel sort by keys

Tags: arrays, laravel, sorting, collections, laravel-5.1

I make an array with collections with code:

```
$hours = Voucher::where('created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->get()->groupBy(function($item)
{
  return $item->created_at->format('H');
});

dd($hours);
```

so I get data like this:

[image]

SO keys are hours (00-23).

How I can arrange it starting by 00, 01, 02, 03 ... ...

Answer (score 13):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortkeys

```
$collection = collect([
    'id' => 22345,
    'first' => 'John',
    'last' => 'Doe',
]);

$sorted = $collection->sortKeys();
```

---

**Update for 5.1**

Since you're using Laravel 5.1 and there is no sortKeys method, you can sort the collection before you group it which should result in the keys being in the correct order.

```
$collection->sort(function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->created_at->format('H'), $b->created_at->format('H'));
})->groupBy(function($item) {
    return $item->created_at->format('H');
});
```

Comment: I write $hours = $hours->sortKeys()l and I got error: 
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method sortKeys does not exist - I use Laravel 5.1

Comment: It's good to tag the version in the question when you're using an older one.

Comment: @AleksPer, I've added an untested update for 5.1.  Should work

Comment: What is the better way to do that? What I need is just {hour: hour->count() } is there some better way to do that ?

Comment: Only 24 hours in a day,  just do a for loop to 24 on the collection in PHP or group by hour in SQL.

Comment: Can you please update the answer above. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: I think that's getting away from the original question.

Comment: Yes, but please show me how... the way I use takes too long. I have vouchers in month then I need to just count how many per hour a day I have so I need resposne like {00h : 114vouchers }

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762022/mysql-number-of-rows-per-hour

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$hours = Voucher::where('created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->get()->sortBy(function($item)
{
  return $item->created_at->format('H');
});
$hours = $hours->groupBy(function($item)
{
  return $item->created_at->format('H');
});
dd($hours);
```